# How to check whether a property exists in a JObject in an Angular App

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, properties, conditional-statements

I need to check whether a given property exists in a JObject, to use with my ng-show directive for my Angular app.

I tried accessing the property using the square brackets syntax:

```
<li ng-show="@Model["punkt1"] != null">@Model.punkt1</li>
```

This is an example of a JSON response:

```
{
  "value": null,
  "editor": {
    "name": "Infobox",
    "alias": "infobox",
    "view": "/App_Plugins/MyGridEditor/infobox.html",
    "render": "/App_Plugins/MyGridEditor/infobox.cshtml",
    "icon": "icon-grid",
    "config": {}
  },
  "active": false,
  "heading": "Toiletter",
  "punkt1": "qwert",
  "punkt2": "qwert"
}
```

There can be up to 5 properties after the "heading" property and I only need to display the ones that are received, meaning the li elements should be removed or hidden if the property is not present in the JSON response.

My above method still doesn't hide the li elements and I am not able to do any checks on properties that do not exist.

Don't mind the properties before the heading.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<li ng-show="@Model.punkt1">@Model.punkt1</li>
```

Comment: That still displays the li elements without content. http://i.imgur.com/A3Sgrnx.png

Comment: Can you use debug and see what values you have for those items? Maybe there are some blank spaces.

Comment: Ah, i think i see what is happening. This is the HTML that is returned on my empty li elements: <li ng-show="!= null"></li> It doesn't have anything to compare with the null, so the condition returns true.

Comment: Is there any other way for me to check whether a property is present in the object and then return false if that is not the case?

Comment: What I typed above should do it. Can you use console.log(@model) to see how it looks like when you load it?

Comment: The model still looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/6Irhoj3.png and my li elements have an empty body.

Comment: That image has a value in the property punkt1. So it will be displayed indeed. I wanted to see how it looks after you debug the code. You might have something else than what you expect from it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153470/discussion-between-leth-and-ice-13).